# How is convolution process done with 4D kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

Applying convolution with kernel of shape (1, 1, 4, 6)to a tensor of shape (2, 3, 2, 4) the result will be (2, 3, 2, 6).

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

tensor = tf.random_uniform([2, 3, 2, 4],0,10, dtype = tf.float32, seed = 0)
kernel = tf.truncated_normal([1, 1, 4, 6], stddev=0.1)
r2 = tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(tensor, kernel, rate=1, padding='SAME')
# Given rate=1 the convolution is with no holes
print(tf.shape(r2)) #-----> tf.Tensor([2 3 2 6], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```

Given that the kernel start with "1, 1" I know nothing happen to the first two dimentions. How do the last two dimentions interact?, how the kernel slide?